# Adjust the width of popup in symfony using messi

Tags: jquery, symfony, popup

I am developing a symfony application, using Messi, a jquery pop up box. I want to change the width of the pop up box,but it is not changing.I tried to set the width attribute,but still it is not changing.

Below given is my render code.

```
$("p a").click(function(e){    
var url = $(this).attr('href');
 Messi.load(url,{title: 'Edit Asset', titleClass: 'info',modal: true,width:'1200px'})
  //Messi.load(url);
 e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Please help.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall your assets. Symfony doesn't automatically copy your assets files (including your js) into web directory. To reinstall assets use next command:

```
php app/console assets:install web
```

By default symfony install assets by hard copying it. But you can add `--symlink` flag to use symlinks instead. Then you will never worry about installing assets because symlink will be placed in the `web` folder and will point to `Resources/public` where you can edit your js.

But when you run `composer install` your assets can be rewritten by hard copied folder. To avoid it you need to change your `composer.json` by adding `"symfony-assets-install": "symlink"` in the `extra` block.